# Count on HABM has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the models Trader, Location and Service

They are setup as per the below

```
class Trader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :traders
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trader
end
```

I would like a specific location to be able to return the traders it contains, in order of the number of services the trader provides.

I have read a few suggestions but only taking into account associations between 2 models where I effectively have 3.  I have put together a ridiculously complex method using arrays, array pointers and case statements which I will spare you reading.

What's the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

I'd add a `:counter_cache` on `Trader`'s `services` association.  Then you can sort by `services_count` and you don't have to reach down to that table at all with a `scope`.

Comment: So I update this as I add services to the Trader?  I already have a before_create/update on Service?

Comment: Have just tried this and realised it wont work as ordering on a service count held in Traders will give me a global count not for the specific Location.